# File size increases significantly after re-projecting

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have processed some aerial imagery using mapsmadeeasy.com, and georeferenced the image using the web tool within MME. However, this is not a very accurate means of georefencing, and delivers a result in EPSG:4326, but our client would like the results projected in EPSG:2193, as we are in New Zealand.

Using the QGIS georefencer tool, i use local government imagery to georeference the imagery that we capture to accurately match the local government imagery.

This is where the problem occurs, the file we download from MapsMadeEasy is a 2.3GB .TiFF, but the resulting file is over 9GB when georeferenced in EPSG:2193.

What is the cause in this huge file size increase, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Reprojecting a raster can turn it on its side up to 45 degrees, which will increase the area as well (NODATA border). Even compressed, it could be significantly larger due to the quirks of dictionary building in LZ77.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS creates uncompressed GeoTIF. For performance reasons uncompressed TIF are often better.You can use Raster/Conversion/Translate from the QGIS menu to convert rasters (or gdal_translate from the command line). Use creation option COMPRESS LZW/JPEG/etc. See possible options: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

For such huge tif I offer you to consider creating mosaic and pyramid (tif overviews) for optimal performance.

Comment: Thank you, I have considered exporting as a JPEG or another lossy format, but did not want to lose any information.

I think there may be another issue, I should have mentioned the site is only around 400 Hectares, and a high quality aerial of this area downloaded from another source is around 50Mb, so there is a huge discrepancy there. 

Even the georeferenced version from MapsMadeEasy is only ~2Gb, which is the highest res version available since all alterations are made from this master, I feel i should be able to at last achieve this size again in a new projection?

Comment: LZW is a lossless compression. However I cannot imagine, you can use such a huge image in an effective way.

Comment: I agree, the file is useless at this size, and suspect it is not a formatting issue causing the file to be so large, and wonder what else may be happening. I am converting to JPEG right now to observe the change in file size, and will try LZW shortly.

Comment: Using compressed raster format in QGIS (or in other GIS)  saves disk space but decreases the performance :(

Answer (score 2):

Also check your image resolution or the number of rows and cols and the data type. If, for some reason, the georeferencing procedure in QGis increased your resolution, you could end up with excess data. Also, if your data has been transformed from int to float, that could give you some extra size.